No sé como programar un bucle en C# que me cambie las propiedades de muchas imagenes en XAML
Necesito simplificar en varias zonas del programa cosas como este ejemplo.
Quisiera ponerlo en un bucle donde solo cambiaría el último carácter por un número.
Ejemplo:
for (numeroEnUnaVariable = 1; 16; numeroEnUnaVariable++)
{ PrimerMedioCuadrado¿numeroEnUnaVariable?.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado};

Código en C# que tengo y que ocupa demasiado espacio:
        //Cuando se carga la Pagina se da el ancho de los cuadrados
        //  que representan las 16 opciones
        anchoMedioCuadrado = (ColumnaPrimeraLinea.ActualWidth - 10 - (15 * 5)) / 32;

        PrimerMedioCuadrado1.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado1.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado2.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado2.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado3.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado3.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado4.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado4.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado5.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado5.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado6.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado6.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado7.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado7.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado8.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado8.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado9.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado9.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado10.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado10.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado11.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado11.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado12.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado12.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado13.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado13.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado14.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado14.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado15.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado15.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        PrimerMedioCuadrado16.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;
        UltimoMedioCuadrado16.Width = anchoMedioCuadrado;


Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Como estas creando esos componentes?

La clave está en reconocer patrones. Un truco que suele funcionar es poner los elementos en un arreglo o una lista, lo intentaste? Esa lista puede ser creada manualmente o si encuentras otra forma, automáticamente

Perdona pero no entiendo, tengo que reconocer que mi nivel es bastante bajo porque hace poco que he empezado.

Si utilizo una lista el problema que me encuentro es que no tengo ni idea de como iré llamando a cada propiedad dentro del bucle, si fuera recoger o poner el dato creo que podria hacerlo, pero pasarlo a la propiedad de una imagen no lo sé hacer

Existen varias formas, te mostraré las 2 que considero más fáciles:
Supondré, a raíz de tu último comentario, que todos los elementos son del tipo Image
1) Recorrer Hijos el Padre
Al panel contendor de todas las imágenes le colocas un nombre y luego recorres los hijos. Algo así se vería el XML
<Grid x:Name="Contenedor">
    <Image x:Name="PrimerMedioCuadrado1" />
    <Image x:Name="UltimoMedioCuadrado1" />
    <!--ETC...-->
</Grid>

foreach(var item in Contenedor.Children)
{
    if(item is Image imagen)
    {
        imagen.Width = 100;
    }
}

Este método funciona siempre y cuando las imágenes sean hijos directos. En caso contrario debes ir recorriendo hijos hasta llegar a la imagen
2) Hacer Binding
Hay muchas formas de hacer Binding, yo lo haré directo a la clase y para ello hay que implementar INotifyPropertyChanged
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _Ancho;
    public double Ancho
    {
        get => _Ancho;
        set
        {
            if (_Ancho != value)
            {
                _Ancho = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext=this;  //Importante establecer el DataContext
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? propertyName=null)
    => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

Asignamos el Binding a las imágenes:
<Image x:Name="PrimerMedioCuadrado1" Width="{Binding Ancho}" />
<Image x:Name="UltimoMedioCuadrado1"  Width="{Binding Ancho}"/>

Y luego
Ancho = (ColumnaPrimeraLinea.ActualWidth - 10 - (15 * 5)) / 32;


Otras formas de hacer lo mismo:

Si creas las imágenes dinámicamente, las vas agregando a una lista y luego recorre las lista
Usando Reflección
Recorriendo el árbol de componentes mediante VisualTreeHelper


Ya entiendo lo que me dices y no se me habia ocurrido, las dos opciones las veo muy factibles y con un codigo muy reducido que es lo que me interesaba.

Gracias, no tengo muy claro como hacer para dar por solucionada la pregunta y darte una merecida medalla, ja, ja ,ja
